# Are there any battle inspired from real life battle?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

According to D.B. Weiss, Battle of bastards is directly inspired from Battle of Canae, even if there are some diferences.

> We went back to the Roman fight against the Carthaginians in the Battle of Cannae where the Romans got caught in an encirclement by Hannibal and just slaughtered to the man

Are there any other battles inspired from real life battles?

Comment: [The Burning of Harrenhal](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Burning_of_Harrenhal) reminds me of [Fort Eben-Emael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Eben-Emael). Both were supposed to be impregnable and the largest in the world, but were attacked from above.

Answer (score 5):

- The [Three Thousand of Qohor](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Three_Thousand_of_Qohor) fought a much larger army of 25.000 Dohtraki screamers. An outnumbered army, defending with spikes and discipline can remind the [Battle of Thermopylae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Thermopylae), a battle that become famous with thanks to the film 300.
  In both battles, the attacker think that the number will be enough to crush the ennemy, and sent several frontal attacks, leading to a slaughter. There are however some huge diferences, the main one being the outcome of the battles, as is the Three Thousand of Qohor battle, the unsullied, whereas the battle of Thermopylae was won by the attacker
- The battle of the bastards is inspired as you say by the battle of Cannae, where Hannibal Barca manage to lure the roman army, and envelop it [image: Cannae]

  It is also inspired by the battle of Agincourt:

  The english crush the french so hard with archers that the corpse become an obstacle to any maneuver

  > For when some of them, killed when battle was first joined, fell at the front, so great was the undisciplined violence and pressure of the mass of men behind that the living fell on top of the dead, and others falling on top of the living were killed as well, with the result that, in each of the three places where the strong contingents guarding our standards were, such a great heap grew of the slain and of those lying crushed in between that our men climbed up those heaps, which had risen above a man’s height, and butchered their enemies down below with swords, axes, and other weapons.
  >
  > <sub>[The Battle of Agincourt: Sources and Interpretations](https://books.google.fr/books?id=H3V2Qv6E5cEC&lpg=PA37&ots=BO6UZPyept&hl=fr&pg=PA37#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>

Comment: War of the Five Kings, Red Wedding, the Wall to some extent. Most of the battles/major events have some historical inspiration though aren’t 1:1 equivalents. I don’t have time to make an answer but that should help you.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot To be fair the question and answer are both specifically about *battles* only. If the answer was all types of historical event you could probably write a book about it (and in fact I'd be surprised if no-one has)

Comment: @user568458 I know but War of the Five Kings is a war containing battles that are likely comparable to those from the War of the Roses. And any battle at the Wall would be comparable to those at Hadrian's Wall.